# Ruby on rails split index.js to separate files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a really huge index.js file, like 7000 lines, and want to split it to separate files, dont care if they will be assembled by rails into the one file, just need to separate them for easier editing.

I have application.js manifest file which includes index.js and many more javascript files, but that index.js became really big since i'm not a Ruby on Rails guy, so can you please give me some useful advise on it?

index.js is:

"use strict";

```
(function($) {
//some setup string vars and arrays

//some object definition
//some object definition
//some object definition
//some object definition

//some conditions to init those objects
})(jQuery)
```

So the

> //some object definition

i want to move to separated files.

Comment: Why are you splitting it into separate files? Is each file going to be JS specific to a certain page?

Comment: Firstly just to make them easy maintable, not to look at 7000 lines js file when editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `application.js` file you can call the following to load the individual files

```
//= require customjsfile1
//= require customjsfile2
...
```

If you only want to call them in your ERB you could instead do `<%= javascript_include_tag "customjsfile1", "data-turbolinks-track" => true  %>`